# Removing line from file

Tags: c++, fstream

I've got an error from compiler:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7486A832 in Nowy.exe: Microsoft C++ 
exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00B3F2F4.
```

After debbuging it seems an error ocurres here:

```
if (plik.good() == true)
{
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    string line;
    while (std::getline(plik, line))
    {
        if (number_of_lines == deleteLineNumber)
        {
            line.replace(0,line.length(), ""); // <--------- HERE IS ERROR
            //cout << "Line has been deleted!";
            break;
        }

        ++number_of_lines;
    }
}
```

Where am I making mistake?
This code was supposed to remove one line from a file

Comment: What is the value of `line` at that point, and what is the value of `line.length()`?

Comment: Your mistake was that you failed to include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137666/c-simple-string-replace-non-complicated-code-but-producing-crazy-error

Comment: I guess line[0] should be 0 and line.lenght() = 30, as file suggest

Answer (score 0):

`std::out_of_range` is an exception you get when you attempt to access memory outside the space you've allocated (in an STL container). In this particular case, you are accessing areas of a `std::string` that has not been allocated:

Try replacing `line[0]` by `line.begin()` and `line.length()` by `line.end()`:

```
line.replace(line.begin(),line.end(), "");
```

If you want to remove the line completely then try:

```
line.erase(line.begin(), line.end());
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But unfortunatelly it didn't solve my problem. Compiler doesn't throw any more errors, but the line which should be deleted from the file still remain after proceeding.

Comment: If you want to remove the line completely try: line.erase(line.begin(),line.end());

Comment: How are you writing the line back to the file? Maybe you are writing `\n` charachter by using `cout<<endl`.

Comment: You need to write the changes to the file.

Comment: `\r\n` = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows

Try writing without them when you delete the line. They are getting printed even though you have erased the string.